# What is the case of ''Eigen'' in the following sentence

Tags: grammatical-case

If it is genitive then can we conclude that if a possessive adjective is in genitive than the following other adjectives will also be in the same case.

> Das größte Risiko ist das Treffen in den vier Wänden Ihrer eigenen Wohnung

Comment: The sentence that I translated is "The greatest risk is having the Date in the four walls of your own apartment." Its from a textbook. Date here is in context of a romantic meeting

Comment: Oh. date = two humans meeting -> Verabredung, Treffen...  *NOT* date = point in time, specific day -> Datum

Comment: Sorry my bad :P

Comment: Non problem. Looking forward to your [edit]. ^_^

Comment: *eigene vier Wände und *Wohnung*  are synonyms

Comment: @AnandSangwan What other case beside genitive would you expect *eigenen* to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Ihr**er** eigen**en** Wohnung_*" is a noun phrase **entirely in Genitive** (where *Wohnung*_ has zero ending (in other words, it's unmarked), but that doesn't change the fact: it could just as well be *Herz* and then the noun would also have the genitive ending, "*Ihr**es** eigen**en** Herz**ens***").

As for the adjective "[***eigen***](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eigen)(see first meaning)", it is weakly declined (schwach dekliniert) following the strongly declined (stark dekliniert) possessive pronoun "*ihr*", which is also in Genitive, and, more importantly, defines the weak declination of "*eigen*".

Comment: Vielen Dank Mein Freund!!!